# not getting the desired output of command tag in HTML

Tags: html, command

I have used command tag and its output is not correct 
here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<menu>
<command onclick="alert('Hello World')">Click here</command>
</menu>
</body>
</html>
```

I am viewing the output in firefox and internet explorer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/command

Comment: The command tag may not be supported in your browser

Comment: @maciekm http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding

Answer (score 0):

The command tag isn't supported by any browsers besides Internet Explorer 9
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_command.asp

Comment: but I am using IE 10!!

Comment: It is supported only in IE 9. IE 10 does not have support

Comment: yes - it is only supported in IE 9.  If you follow the link and select "Try it yourself" you'll get the message when you click 'Save'.  Try it in compatibility mode.

Comment: It is “supported” by IE 9 only in the sense that IE 9 implements it as an unknown element, more or less like it were a `span` element, so any general attributes can be used with it. By the drafts, the element was meant to be empty, and this is how modern browsers parse it, even though they do not implement it. Please don’t cite w3schools, it is full of misinformation (like in this case, describing the element as being “HTML5”—it is not in the current HTML5 CR).

Answer (score 0):

The `<command>` tag is currently supported only in IE 9 not earlier or later versions, or any other browser.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_command.asp

Answer (score 0):

The `command` element has been proposed in various drafts, including the [first HTML5 CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/) in 2012 (where it was marked as being “at risk” due to lack of implementations), but it has been dropped from newer drafts. Any implementations of it, and the associated Command API, should thus be considered as experimental.

The current drafts have the [`menuitem` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menuitem) for similar purposes. But note that it is just a proposed element, it is not present in the currentl [HTML5 CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), and it probably has just limited experimental implementation in Firefox.

The conclusions depend on what you are trying to achieve. The idea of `command` was to provide, together with the `menu` element`, a way of setting up a dropdown menu of scripted operations. In the simplest case, you can do such things with the normal`select`element with an`onchange` attribute with a value that performs different operations, depending on the index of the selected option.